# Remote command substitution fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

What is missing here?

This works (proves the file is there):

```
[rundeck@den16 ~]$ ssh ${SSH_USER}@${BUILD_HOST} "cat ${WLS_E1DOMAIN_LOC}/nodemanager.process.id"
7504
```

This doesn't (says No such file or directory):

```
[rundeck@den16 ~]$ ssh ${SSH_USER}@${BUILD_HOST} "kill -9 `cat ${WLS_E1DOMAIN_LOC}/nodemanager.process.id`"
cat: /cygdrive/c/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/E1DevDomain/nodemanager/nodemanager.process.id: No such file or directory

kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

Comment: to avoid the `cat` try `pkill -F /path/to/pid`

Comment: `kill -9` is rude.

Comment: I would go one step further and say that `kill -9` is a bug either in your script (it should simply use `kill`) or in the program you try to kill (it's broken if it requires you to use `kill -9` to actually kill it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a kill command to a server over ssh.

Unfortunately, all substitutions are done on the host side, and not the server side. The error you are getting from `cat` is an error which is generated on `den16` and not `BUILD_HOST`. If you want to pass it to `BUILD_HOST` you have to use a pipe in this case. Normally you would use single quotes, but since you use shell variables already in there, you have to use a pipe

```
rundeck@den16 ~]$ ssh ${SSH_USER}@${BUILD_HOST} "cat ${WLS_E1DOMAIN_LOC}/nodemanager.process.id | xargs kill -9"
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution was spot-on. Also, thanks for pointing out the useful stuff that all command substitutions are done on client side itself - very useful input.

Answer (score 3):

As @kvantour said, the problem is that the command expansion is happening on the local computer. Another way to solve this is to use escapes to tell the local shell to pass through the characters that normally trigger command expansion:

```
ssh ${SSH_USER}@${BUILD_HOST} "kill -9 \`cat ${WLS_E1DOMAIN_LOC}/nodemanager.process.id\`"
                                       ^                                               ^
```

BTW, I also recommend using `$( )` instead of backticks (and you only have to escape the `$`, not the parentheses):

```
ssh ${SSH_USER}@${BUILD_HOST} "kill -9 \$(cat ${WLS_E1DOMAIN_LOC}/nodemanager.process.id)"
                                       ^
```

BTW^2, you can use `echo` on the command part of the `ssh` command to see what'll be sent to the remote computer. That is, it shows the command after the local shell has done its parsing, substitutions, etc, but before the remote shell has done its parsing etc. Like this:

```
$ WLS_E1DOMAIN_LOC=/some/path
$ echo "kill -9 \$(cat ${WLS_E1DOMAIN_LOC}/nodemanager.process.id)"
kill -9 $(cat /some/path/nodemanager.process.id)
```

Here, you can see that `$WLS_E1DOMAIN_LOC` did get substituted by the local shell, but the command substitution didn't.

(This is one of very few cases where `echo`ing a command is informative, rather than misleading.)